# Windows environment variables at appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables, appsettings

I'm trying to set `AccessKeys` in `appsettings.Development.json` to point to my OneDrive folder. Since some team members have their OneDrive at different folders, I was trying to use Windows environment variables like this:

```
"AppSettings": {
    "AccessKeys": "%OneDrive%\\project123\\keys\\",
}
```

However, the above attempt is not working since the file is not being found.

```
    internal XDocument ReturnFileContent(string filename)
    {
        string documentPath = _configuration["AppSettings:AccessKeys"];
        string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(documentPath, filename);

        var aux = File.Exists(xmlFilePath); <- always false

        //...
    }
```

Comment: Are you averse to using the User Secrets system? That way each person has their own settings that do not leave their machine (no accidental committing to source control etc)

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to use Windows environment variables, as asked?